# A good practice to handle errors in Swift + SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently making my first steps in Swift Concurrency (using async/await/actors). When it comes to integrating functions that are handled in Tasks (via Swift Concurrency), I am currently using this concept to handle errors:

`Model.swift`

```swift
public func submit() async {
    self.isSubmitting = true
    defer { self.isSubmitting = false }
    
    do {
        let result = await worker()
    } catch {
        self.hasErrorOccurred = true
        self.errorDescription = error.localizedDescription
    }

    self.hasSubmittedSuccessfully = true
}
```

`ContentView.swift`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                Task {
                    await model.submit()
                }
            }) { Text("Submit") }

            if model.hasErrorOccurred {
                Text(model.errorDescription)
            }

            if model.hasSubmittedSuccessfully {
                Text("Success")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering if this is good practice to handle error or success feedback with this approach. How do you treat this?

Comment: I'm working on a small error handling framework that passes them up the view hierarchy until a view handles them. Tonight I'm going to add support for "Alertable" errors, and a ViewModifier that automatically displays an alert when an error is triggered. You can find the WIP here https://github.com/EmilioPelaez/ErrorHierarchy. Feel free to reach out to me if you want to discuss it further :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those boolean flags are not a good practice.

My suggestion is an enum with associated values

```
enum WorkResult {
    case none, success(String), failure(Error)
}
```

Adopt `ObservableObject` in `Model`, declare a `@Published` property and assign the cases in the `submit` method. This will update the view. This simple example returns the string "Hello" after two seconds.

```
@MainActor
class Model : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var submission : WorkResult = .none
   
    public func submit() async {
        do {
            let result = try await worker()
            submission = .success(result)
        } catch {
            submission = .failure(error)
        }

    }
    
    func worker() async throws -> String {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2_000_000_000)
        return "Hello"
    }
}
```

In the view `switch` on the enum and handle the cases

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                Task {
                    await model.submit()
                }
            }) { Text("Submit") }
            switch model.submission {
                case .success(let result): Text(result)
                case .failure(let error): Text(error.localizedDescription)
                default: EmptyView()
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good proposal!

Comment: Task actually returns a built-in result type